# Create element in jQuery, then insert it with an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an element and then inserting it, but it isn't quite working as expected. To create the element:

```
var showChildren = $("<span>", { text: "[arrow]", class: "show-children" });
```

Then to insert it, i tried:

```
$("body").append(showChildren);
```

But nothing was displayed, so I inspected the object then tried this instead:

```
$("body").append(showChildren[0].outerHTML);
```

This displays the element as expected, but seems a little awkward. My goal is to then attach an event handler to it. I thought something like this might work:

```
showChildren.on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a better way to create an element, display it, and attach a listener to it?

Comment: *"But nothing was displayed"* It ought to have been, can you produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: [Your code works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/xkcxdjkq/) Are you sure `$ === jQuery` in your example, and it's an up-to-date version?

Comment: Seems to work fine in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5tb4mer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a better way, I don't know whats better, it could all just be subjective per developer. But here is another way to create, append and attach listener using chaining.

```
$("<span>", {
    text: "[arrow]",
    class: "show-children"
}).appendTo('body').on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

And the code you wrote above seems to work fine in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5tb4mer/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. By pointing out that it worked there, I did some more debugging and found out the problem was related to the fact that I was trying to append the object inside a loop, so it kept moving to the next item in the loop. I thought taking the loop out of my question would help explain the issue, but it ended up bypassing it.

Comment: Gotcha. Well happy to help, even unintentionally! =]

Answer (score 1):

For appending, unless there's a compelling reason, just build the HTML manually without using jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<span class="show-children">[arrow]</span>');
```

For the event, use delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '.show-children', function (e) {
  $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
});
```

You can do the event attachment in your document ready handler, once, and it will fire no matter how many times you append that HTML.